# What is the 'criticality' attribute in SimplePagedResultsControl in python-ldap?

Tags: python-ldap

I'm using python-ldap for pagination of LDAP search.
I found many similar references online and all of them set:
`page_control = SimplePagedResultsControl(True, size={some_size}, cookie='')`
For example: https://medium.com/@alpolishchuk/pagination-of-ldap-search-results-with-python-ldap-845de60b90d2
I checked python-ldap's documentation and couldn't find a useful explanation:
https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap-controls.html#ldap.controls.libldap.SimplePagedResultsControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2696

```
If the server does not support pagedResultsControl, 
the server MUST return an error of unsupportedCriticalExtension if the client
requested it as critical, otherwise the server SHOULD ignore the control.
```